# Highlight text in a treeviw node by code

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple function, in VB 10, that search for a string in all the nodes of a treeview; it works, but after expanding the node with the found string, the icon of the same item is changed to "selected" but the text is not highlighted and I dont understand why...

```
Public Sub SearchInTV(TV As TreeView, strSearch As String)
    Dim Nd() As TreeNode

    Nd = TV.Nodes.Find(strSearch, True)
    If Nd.Count > 0 Then
        Nd(0).EnsureVisible()
        TV.SelectedNode = Nd(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look in properties of TreeView control...is HideSelection = False?

Comment: yeahhhh.... it works... :-) it was 'True'. Thank you very much... :-)